# How to show total comments count of the current logged in user?

Tags: wp-comment-query

I'm creating a custom user status page for my members. I need to show the comments count of the `wp_get_current_user()`. I looked at `WP_Comment_Query` but unable to understand anything.

My conditions are:

- comment_type : review_comment
- comment_approved : 1

Comment: Is review_comment correct? I don't think that's a standard type.

Comment: But you want to look at the comment on the constructor for the documentation on the args array to pass. You probably want count = true, author__in for the current user ID, status = approve and comment_type = review_comment.

Comment: @Rup review_comment is my custom comment type. I want to show results as  - 1 review, 2 review, 10 review etc.